# Fetching a remote branch without local changes

Tags: git

I'm trying to fetch a remote branch onto my machine without any local changes. For exmaple, if the two repositories look like this:

Remote:

```
master: A -> B -> C -> D
```

Local:

```
master: A -> B -> E -> F
change: A -> B -> E -> F -> G -> H
```

Then I'd like for my resulting local repository to look like this:

```
master: A -> B -> C -> D
change: A -> B -> E -> F -> G -> H
```

Comment: I wonder how would you end in the state where your local and remote masters diverge as you describe? and also, doing what you describe would make it hard for you to rebase?

Comment: What is `change`? If it just stands for something like `origin/master` you should be able to get away with `git remote update`.

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan its easy to imagine actually. OP pulled while *remote* `master` was at `B` then made a few commits `E` and `F` and in the mean while remote `master` went from `B` to `C` to `D`. `git pull --rebase` could be used. right?

Comment: @hus787 - if one does a `git pull --rebase`, wouldn't it change it to have the sequence of `ABCDEF`? i.e. `E` and `F` would be rebased over the remote `ABCD`?

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan of course it will but you said "hard" to `rebase` that's I mentioned it. And  to clarify `E` and `F` will no longer remain `E` and `F` (hashes) because they will be lost and only the changes they have made will remain.

Comment: @hus787 - I see what you mean. When I said hard to rebase - I meant preserving changes without messy merge conflicts. I was wondering what the OP wishes to do about E and F once master is changed to 'ABCD' in local.

Comment: `change` is just the name of a branch. This situation arose when I made a few changes on my local `master` branch, and then switched to a new branch to make changes. I realized I didn't want to release the changes I made to `master` yet, but I needed to make a quick change and push it out. In hindsight, I should have been working on a different branch from the start.

Comment: @LandonSchropp in that case `git reset --hard B` followed by `git pull` would do

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan a minor correction to my statement `E` and `F` are not actually lost. OP could later, after making the quick change, merge `change` into `master` or `git rebase change` while in `master`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do:

```
git checkout change
git branch -D master
git checkout master
```

Comment: Is there any way I could do this while targeting a remote repository (i.e. something other than the origin)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

Of course, this carries the usual caveats about `reset --hard`, which throws away data. Here, you asked to throw away data, so I don't imagine that's a problem.

Comment: would it be right to say that you are assuming that the remote in OP's case is named *origin*?

Comment: I am actually tracking a different remote (`gt`). When I try running `git reset --hard gt/master`, I get this error: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'gt': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`